# Singly linked list implementation in Java without help of java.util.linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list

I am learning Java and as a first exercise I tried to implement singly linked list without the help of `java.util`. I tested my program for basic operations and it seems to work fine. But I still want to know if there are any improvements I could do in terms of design or implementation in OOP.

**Node.java**

```
            public class Node{ 

            // immutable class representing head node of linked list

            private DataItems dataItems;
            private Node nextNode;

            public void setNextNode(Node _nextNode){
                this.nextNode=_nextNode;
            }

            public Node getNextNode(){
                return nextNode;
            }

            public DataItems getDataItems(){
                return dataItems;
            }

            public void setDataItems(DataItems _dataItems){
                this.dataItems=_dataItems;
            }

            }
```

**HeadNode.java**

```
public class HeadNode{ 

// immutable class representing head node of linked list

Node nextNode;

public void setNextNode(Node _nextNode) {
    nextNode=_nextNode;
}

public Node getNextNode() {
    return nextNode;
}

}
```

**DataItems.java**

```
public class DataItems{

private int key;
private String value;

public DataItems(int _key, String _value){
    this.key=_key;
    this.value=_value;
}

public int getKey() {
    return key;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public String toString() {
    return "("+getKey()+","+getValue()+")";
}

}
```

**LinkedList.java**

```
public class LinkedList{

HeadNode head;

public LinkedList(){
    head = new HeadNode();
}

// insert node at the beginning of the list
public void insertNode(DataItems _data){
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.setDataItems(_data);
    Node nextNode = head.getNextNode();
    head.setNextNode(newNode);
    newNode.setNextNode(nextNode);
}

// delete node at the beginning of the list
public void deleteNode(){
    Node toBeDeletedNode = head.getNextNode();
    if(toBeDeletedNode!=null) {
        Node nextNode = toBeDeletedNode.getNextNode();
        head.setNextNode(nextNode);
        toBeDeletedNode.setNextNode(null);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No nodes to be deleted");
    }

}

// display all nodes data
public void displayList(){
    Node nodes = head.getNextNode();
    int i=0;
    while(nodes!=null) {
        DataItems data = nodes.getDataItems();
        System.out.println("Node "+i+" : "+data.toString());
        nodes = nodes.getNextNode();
        i++;
    }
}

// reverse order of linked list
public void reverseLinkedList(){
    int sizeOfList = size();
    Node lastNode = nodeAtIndex(sizeOfList-1);
    Node snode, tnode;
    for(int i=sizeOfList-2;i>=0;i--){
        snode = nodeAtIndex(i);
        tnode = snode.getNextNode();
        tnode.setNextNode(snode);
    }
    nodeAtIndex(0).setNextNode(null);
    head.setNextNode(lastNode);
}

// reverse order of linked list
public void searchKey(int _key){
    int i=0;
    DataItems data = dataAtNodeIndex(i);
    while(data!=null){
        if(data.getKey()== _key){
            System.out.println("Node at index : "+i+" has data item : "+data.toString());
        }
        i++;
        data = dataAtNodeIndex(i);
    }
}

// insert a node at index
public void insertNodeAtIndex(int _index, DataItems _data){
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.setDataItems(_data);
    if(_index==0) {
        insertNode(_data);
    } else {
        Node prevNode = nodeAtIndex(_index-1);
        if(prevNode!=null) {
            Node nextNode = prevNode.getNextNode();
            newNode.setNextNode(nextNode);
            prevNode.setNextNode(newNode);
        }
    }
}

// delete a node at index
public void deleteNodeAtIndex(int _index){
    if(_index==0) {
        deleteNode();
    } else {
        Node prevNode = nodeAtIndex(_index-1);
        if(prevNode!=null) {
            Node targetNode = prevNode.getNextNode();
            Node nextNode = targetNode.getNextNode();
            targetNode.setNextNode(null);
            prevNode.setNextNode(nextNode);
        }
    }
}

// return data item at particular node
public DataItems dataAtNodeIndex(int _index){
    Node nodes = nodeAtIndex(_index);
    if(nodes!=null) {
    return nodes.getDataItems();
} else {
    return null;
}
}

// return node at particular index
private Node nodeAtIndex(int _index){
    if(_index<0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        Node nodes = head.getNextNode();
        int i=0;
        while(i<_index && nodes!=null) {
            nodes = nodes.getNextNode();
            i++;
        }
        return nodes;
    }
}

// return the size of linked list
public int size() {
    int count=0;
    Node nodes = nodeAtIndex(count);
    while(nodes!=null) {
        nodes = nodeAtIndex(++count);
    }
    return count;
}

}
```

**Tester.java**

```
public class Tester{

public static void main(String[] args){

// create new linked list
LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();

// insert 5 data to the list
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    DataItems data = new DataItems(i,"Data_"+i);
    ll.insertNode(data);
}
System.out.println("\n");

// display the inserted data
System.out.println("5 inserted datas are : \n");
ll.displayList();
System.out.println("\n");

// testing deleting node at the beginning
System.out.println("list after deleting first node data : \n");
ll.deleteNode();
ll.displayList();
System.out.println("\n");

// testing deleting node at the index
System.out.println("list after deleting second index data : \n");
ll.deleteNodeAtIndex(2);
ll.displayList();
System.out.println("\n");

// testing inserting node at the index
System.out.println("list after inserting second index data : \n");
DataItems data = new DataItems(11,"Data_11");
ll.insertNodeAtIndex(2,data);
ll.displayList();
System.out.println("\n");

// testing searching node with key
System.out.println("Searching list for key 11 : \n");
ll.searchKey(11);
System.out.println("\n");
System.out.println("size of list : "+ll.size());
System.out.println("\n");

// testing reversing linked list
System.out.println("list after reversing linked list : \n");
ll.reverseLinkedList();
ll.displayList();
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've only glanced at your code, but two things stood out.

## Immutable

In `HeadNode` you have a comment:

```
// immutable class representing head node of linked list
```

Either [immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html) doesn't mean what you think it does, or this comment is confused.  Immutable classes don't change after they've been constructed.  They typically have final members so that they can't be assigned to.  You `HeadNode` class provides bother a getter and a setter for its only field `nextNode`.  This isn't an immutable class.

## Testing

Rather than rolling your own tests in `main`, consider looking into a testing framework like [JUnit](http://junit.org/junit4/).  It allows you to encapsulate tests for different functionality in a more expressive way, so that you can clearly tell from the test runs what is failing if you introduce bugs.

A few afterthoughts to add to [@Jonas](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/152112/4203)' answer.

## Node

At the moment you have a distinction between nodes that have data (`Node`) and nodes that don't have data (`HeadNode`).  Does it really make sense to have a `Node` that doesn't have a dataitem associated with it?  Looking at your code, the answer is probably not, the first thing you do after creating a new Node is to call `setDataItems`.  With that in mind, it would be better to add a constructor to your `Node` class that takes in a data item, rather than requiring the client to call a member function immediately after construction.

## Efficiency

As @Janos pointed out, some of your methods are not very efficient.  The one that most struck me was your `searchKey` method.  It relies on your `dataAtNodeIndex` method which in turn relies on `nodeAtIndex`.  Since your `nodeAtIndex` always starts from head, you end up searching the list over and over again from the start, going one item further each time until you find they key you're looking for.

## Error Checking

Some of your methods can fail, but don't have a method for telling the client.  For example, `insertNodeAtIndex` and `deleteNodeAtIndex` both return void.  They also have ways that they can fail to deliver on their promises and fail silently.  If a client calls `insertNodeAtIndex(5)` when the list only has 3 items, then you have a few options.  At the moment, you effectively ignore the request (the client has no way to know that the item hasn't been added to the list).  It would be better to at the item to the tail of the list (this fulfils the insert promise).  However, it would be better still to throw an exception to indicate to the client that they've made an invalid request and that the item hasn't been inserted into the list.

Comment: Thanks forsvarir. Yes, I had misunderstood concept. I will take a look at Junit.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to forsvarir's Answer:

## Code Style

### Whitespace

Try to use whitespace more consistently.
Correct indentation can make code much more readable.
Sometimes you put a space before the opening braces after a method definition or around operators (`=`, `+`, etc.), sometimes you don't.
I won't tell you to put spaces there or to leave them out, that's mostly personal preference or convention (I prefer putting spaces), but when you decide to do one or the other, stick to it.

### Parameter Names

All your method parameter's names start with an underscore, which doesn't look particularly nice. If you're already using the `this`-Keyword to access your object's properties, there is no need to give the parameter a different name than your attributes, since prefixing the name with `this.` will already tell Java to use the object's property instead of the parameter.

### Method Names

`insertNode` gives the impression it inserts a `Node` at a freely specified point in the list.
Actually, it does neither: it adds the element at the front of the list (making it the new head) and it (from the user's perspective) doesn't add a `Node`, but a `DataItems` element to the list.
Maybe `prependElement` would be better suited here.
Same goes for `deleteNode` and generally any method with "node" in its name - of course it is a linked list and thus uses nodes underneath, but that detail should probably be hidden from the user.

### Class Names

`DataItems` only represents a single item, it would be better to not use the pllural form for its name.

## Architecture

### Unnecessary `HeadNode`

Your `LinkedList` stores a reference to a `HeadNode`. `HeadNode`s only purpose seems to be to hold a reference to a `Node`, so why not remove the `HeadNode`-class altogether and directly use a `Node` in your `LinkedList`?

### Coupling

Your `LinkedList` and `Node` implementations directly use the `DataItems` class for storing data.
The whole linked list-scenario seems like a perfect example for learning to use Java's Generics: That way you can not only use your `LinkedList` to store `DataItems`, but any object.
You can modify `DataItems` in the same way to use any type as key or value.
See [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) for more information on that topic.

If you implemented your list like this, you could also consider implementing Java's [`List<E>` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to make it completely interchangable with other `List`-type in Java.
While that violates not using the `java.util` package, it offers quite a range of new things to learn, while trying to implement all methods required by the interface.

Of course, when you use Generics instead of `DataItems` directly, your `searchKey` method cannot be implemented as it is now.
Instead, you'd need a method (let's call it `find`), which takes a predicate (i.e. a function taking the datatype stored in your list and returning a `true` if the item matches whatever you're looking for) as its parameter.

### Implementation

#### Insertion and Deletion

Your `insertNode` and `deleteNode` methods both are called when executing `insertNodeAtIndex(0, data)` and `deleteNodeAtIndex(0)`, respectively.
I recommend doing it the other way around, i.e. calling `deleteNodeAtIndex(0)` from `deleteNode` in order to keep the insertion/deletion code neatly in a single method instead of splitting it over two separate methods.
Also, I would move the method definitions closer together, so you don't have to search too much to find the related method.
Always try to keep methods with similar responsibilities closely together in the source file.

#### Reversing the List

Your implementation of `reverseLinkedList` is pretty inefficient.
For each node in your list, it calls the `nodeAtIndex` method, which itself iterates over the whole list, causing it to fall in the \$O(n²)\$ group of algorithms.
Reversing the list could be done in \$O(n)\$ when using a `Stack` or recursion.

#### Calculating the List's Size

This implementation, too, is in \$O(n²)\$ while it could be done in \$O(n)\$.
Instead of always calling `nodeAtIndex`, just put the first node in a variable and in the while loop, check if the element is `null`, incrementing `count` and replacing the node with the next node.

Comment: Thank you. This is useful. I just have one doubt - would it be good idea to use method overloading instead of having two methods `insertNode` and `insertNodeAtIndex`.

Comment: @ShilpaRamesh that depends on where you want to go with your list implementation. As long as the method continues to take a `DataItems` object and an optional index, it should be clear what gets inserted where. If you go the Generics route, this kind of overloading may confuse a user: Think of `LinkedList<Integer>`. Will `list.insertNode(1, 2)` insert a node of value 1 at index 2 or value 2 at index 1? `insertNodeAtIndex` would imply the former, while `insertNode` doesn't really imply anything.
Method overloading can be great, but always try to make the caller's life easier.